# The return value of "reduce" must be used

Tags: angular, sonarqube

below is my reduce code

```
        filtersArray.reduce((acc, {field, operator, value}) => {    
            value = btoa(value);
            value = value.toString();
            if (columnList.length > 0) {
              columnList = [];
            }
            filterObject['attributeName'] = field;   
            filterObject['FilterValue'] = value;
            filterObject['FilterOperator'] = operator;    
            columnList.push(filterObject);    
            return acc;
          }, {});
```

I am getting an issue in sonarqube saying that the retun value of reduce must be used. What changes do I need to make to this script to bypass the issue? Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: use forEach method

Answer (score 1):

You aren't doing anything with the return value of `reduce`.
You could store the return value of reduce:

```
      const foo = filtersArray.reduce((acc, {field, operator, value}) => {    
        value = btoa(value);
        value = value.toString();
        if (columnList.length > 0) {
          columnList = [];
        }
        filterObject['attributeName'] = field;   
        filterObject['FilterValue'] = value;
        filterObject['FilterOperator'] = operator;    
        columnList.push(filterObject);    
        return acc;
      }, {});
```